# How to subset a matrix and find out shortest path between all nodes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, path, subset, shortest

I have a matrix:

```
       1          2         3         4         5         6    
   1 0.7431    0.2769    0.0000    0.1869    0.2760    0.9597
   2 0.2769    0.0462    0.0344    0.4898    0.6797    0.3404
   3 0.0000    0.0344    0.4387    0.4456    0.6551    0.0000
   4 0.1869    0.4898    0.4456    0.6463    0.1626    0.2238
   5 0.2760    0.6797    0.6551    0.1626    0.1190    0.7513
   6 0.9597    0.3404    0.0000    0.2238    0.7513    0.2551
```

Integers are index. I have a hash table in which each index is a person. Decimals are interactions between indices. Now I want to subset this matrix with a index list (1, 3, 6), which means I only care the interaction among 1, 3 and 6.

```
Subset:

       1             3              6
    1 0.7431       0.0000          0.9579

    3 0.0000       0.4387          0.0000

    6 0.9579       0.0000          0.2551
```

There are no interactions between some people, e.g. person 1 and 3 or person 3 and 6. But 1 is interacts with 2, 4, 5 and 6 which interact with 3. So 1 interacts 3 through 2, 4, 5 or 6. It can be 1->2->4->3 or 1->4->3 something like that. I want to find the shortest path for those 2 nodes that have no direct interactions. I want to subset the original matrix and then find the shortest path between the nodes that don't have interactions.
Sorry guys, I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: What do you mean by distances between all nodes and shortest paths?

Comment: Can you provide a small numerical example?  I'm with @mikkola where I don't understand what it is you want.

Comment: Is this a matrix of weights in a complete graph?  If so, why do you have non-zero values on the diagonal?

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, that helps, but it is still confusing to have a non-zero weight on the (1,1) interaction, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm):

There is a Mathworks file exchange algorithm that calculates Dijkstra's algorithm here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36140-dijkstra-algorithm

I have used it to calculate shortest paths before...it's pretty efficient and guaranteed optimal.  There's really no need to subset the matrix...if there are nodes you don't want to consider, just don't put them in your matrix.